# В Jenkins при сборке в консоли неправильно отображается кириллица

Tags: java, кодировка, gradle, centos, jenkins

Всем привет!
При запуске сборки в Jenkins, в консоли кириллица заменяется символами:

```
@first
    ��������: ����������� ���� ���������� # src/test/resources/self-test/test.feature:5
```

Проект использует Java, собирается в Gradle.
Сборка выполняет команду Windows:

```
cd c:\..\..\
gradle clean test
```

Jenkins крутится на сервере с CentOS 7

```
$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

При локальном запуске на Win10 из cmd все работает правильно, вывод в консоль корректный. (В системе включена поддержка UTF-8)
В билде грейдла тоже добавлены параметры кодировки для джавы (это запуск теста):

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "utf-8"
}
```

В настройки запуска дженкинса на сервере тоже добавлен параметр запуска с кодировкой UTF-8:

```
# Arguments for the Jenkins JVM
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
```

Ну, и добавление в строку запуска сборки *chcp 65001* тоже не помогло.
Что еще можно попробовать поправить?
Буду признателен, если кто-то сможет коротко объяснить, что именно происходит.

Comment: вероятно, в каком-то из ваших файлов текст не в utf8. найдите, исправьте, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Александр, например, о каких файлах речь?

Comment: вам виднее. например, тот, который вы упомянули в тексте вопроса. ну и вообще поищите кириллицу в разных кодировках. буква `о`, например, наиболее [часто](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) встречается в русском языке.

Comment: Так проблема в том, что тест в ходе работы выводит в консоль текст на кириллице.
С запуском этого теста в среде Windows проблем нет. Проблемы появляются при выводе этого текста в консоль сборки.
Сама машина подключена к дженкинсу в качестве ноды и локально на ней все работает правильно.